# Solving a linear system $Ax=$(eigenvector(s))

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Question: Suppose $A$ is a real, symmetric, $(3\times 3)$ matrix with eigenvalues $0,a, $ and, $b$ with corresponding orthonormal eigenvectors $u,v,w.$ Can the systems $Ax=u$ or $Ax=v+w$ be solved?

My attempt: I used the canonical diagonalization $A=S^{-1}\Lambda S$ and so have the system $\Lambda S=Su$ which is something I suppose I could write out, but isn't too enlightening. Instead, I checked the nullspace of $A,$ and I believe it is spanned by $(0, 0, 1)^T,$ and so the row space is spanned by $(1, 0, 0)^T,(0, 1, 0)^T$ by rank-nullity and Gram-Schmidt. Could I use these facts and the Fredholm alternative to answer the questions? If so, how, and if not, what else should I try?

Comment: (I am assuming that $a\neq 0, b\neq 0$.) You know that ${\cal R} A \subset \operatorname{sp} \{ v,w\}$, so $Ax=u$ cannot have a solution. Since $A(c_1 v + c_2 w) = a c_1 v + b c_2 w$, I think you can figure this one out.

Comment: Of course! Overthinking can be insidious sometimes...

Comment: I need to think about that...